# how to run cron job in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cron

I am trying to delete data from database using cron job in cakephp . I have created a TestShell.php file at /app/Console/Command/TestShell.php with the following code:

```
<?php
class TestShell extends AppShell {

    public $uses = array('BillsReceivable'); 

    public function main() {
        $this->BillsReceivable->deleteAll(array(
          'BillsReceivable.days >='=>30, 
        ));
        $this->out('Records deleted..');
    }
}
```

My cron command is:

```
/home/bigzip/public_html/TimeZip/app/Console/cake -app /home/bigzip/public_html/TimeZip/app TestShell
```

but its not working.please help.

Comment: How's it 'not working'? Please provide more details about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /home/bigzip/public_html/TimeZip/app/
sudo Console/cake test
```

Comment: nothing.delete function not working.the table data is not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

## cakephp cron job

cd /full/path/to/app && Console/cake myshell myparam 
`-working` defines the working directory

`/home/bigzip/public_html/TimeZip/app/Console/cake.php -app /home/bigzip/public_html/TimeZip/app -working /home/bigzip/public_html/TimeZip/app TestShell` 
The above code should help you out

Comment: Add some comments to your answer.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to add working dir. The existing answer was already correct enough.